# JSX/Babel highlighting in PyCharm

Tags: javascript, pycharm, babeljs, reactjs

I'm using PyCharm for a combined Flask/React project. I've got my JavaScript version set to "JSX Harmony" in settings, but my code highlighting still looks like this:

[image: No JSX highlighting]

Is there a plugin I can install to enable the JSX highlighting available in WebStorm, but in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Turns out you need to be inside a standalone JS file, not an inline script.